# Cauchy Integral formula application

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to use local Cauchy integral formula to find the value of

$\int_{ \vert z \vert=2}(z+1)^{-2}\ e^z\ dz.$

So what I am having some troubles when trying to make this integral in the form

$\int_{\gamma} \frac{f( \zeta)}{\zeta-z} dz$, so could any one please help me with that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $$\frac{e^z}{(z-(-1))^2}=\frac{\frac{e^z-e^{-1}}{z-(-1)}}{z-(-1)}+\frac1e \frac{1}{(z-(-1))^2}$$

Comment: Yeah but what about the value of this integration. We have here $\zeta =-1$ so the first function is not defined at -1

Comment: The numerator of the first term has a removable singularity which once removed renders the numerator an entire function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reduce the integral in this form $\int_{\gamma} \frac{f( z)}{z-\alpha} dz$ then $f( z)=\frac{e^z}{z+1}$ is not analytic in $|z|=2$. You can use the cauchy's integral formula in derivative form $$f^n(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac {f(w)dw}{(w-z)^{n+1}} \,ds,$$ where $C$ is simple closed curve in which $f(w)$ in analytic and $z$ is interior to $C$.

Therefore $$\int_{|z|=2} \frac {e^z}{(z+1)^2}=\frac{2\pi i}{1!}e^{-1}=\frac{2\pi i}{e}.$$ Here note that $f(w)=e^w$.

Comment: did you mean e^-1?

Comment: Yes of course. I corrected it.